# What is Ad-hoc microphone array?

Tags: audio-processing, array-signal-processing

I have stumbled upon this term in many papers, though no one bothers to elaborate. Is this the case where I do not have prior knowledge of the array structure? or otherwise is it the number of microphones available? Maybe both?

Comment: I would guess a known number of microphones in an unknown spatial configuration. If you have access to their signal, you know the number of microphones.

Comment: "Ad hoc" really just means "done without prior planning". That sadly doesn't answer any of your further questions, so it's always going to have to be stated (or be clear from context) in your papers what the answers to these are.